# Journal Acceptance/Rejection dataset with timeline

Tags: data-request, academia

I am looking for a dataset to answer this Academia Stackexchange question:

[Are rejections usually quick?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/112373/8513)

I know some conferences/journals in field have been collecting datasets on the review process, which has resulted in some datasets like 
[Paper Reviews sentiment analysis data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Paper+Reviews)
To answer this question though, I need a dataset that has more details on the timing, e.g. submission date, reviewer assigned date, review complete date,
as well as if it is an accept or a reject.

Answer (score 1):

First, [SciRev](https://scirev.org/) crowdsources and showcases data like that (but it is still sparsely populated, it seems to me).

[Here](https://scirev.org/reviews/ieee-access/) is an example with *IEEE Access*:

[image: SciRev experiences with the journal IEEE Access]

Second, [Publons](https://publons.com/) should likewise have such data - but as an entity belonging to a large commercial enterprise, I fear they will not make their granular data available publicly. You could nevertheless browse around to see how useful the website is for your purpose.

Third, [Academic Accelerator](https://academic-accelerator.com/) seems to collect such data as well (again, [here](https://academic-accelerator.com/Review-Speed/IEEE-Access) is an example with *IEEE Access*).